# Error in Math.data.frame…non-numeric variable in data frame

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, error-message

I have been trying to get some descriptive information from my dataset using R. The following code gives me error:

```
round(aggregate (ffqlong$DMFS_incidence~ffqlong$par_edu,ffqlong, summary),2)
```

and the error is as follows:

```
Error in Math.data.frame(list(`ffqlong$par_edu` = 1:3, `ffqlong$DMFS_incidence` = c(-4,  : 
nicht numerische Variable in data frame: ffqlong$par_edu
```

However, when I use a similar code with a different variable (given below), it produces results.

```
round(aggregate (ffqlong$DMFS_incidence~ffqlong$geschl,ffqlong, summary),2)
```

I calculated the incidence of dental caries (`DMFS_incidence`) and it ranges from -4 to 14 and is coded as numeric variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `round`:

It looks like `par_edu` is a factor, not a numeric, so you cannot round the `par_edu` column in your aggregate.

You have two solutions:

1. Convert `par_edu` to numeric: `ffqlong$par_edu = as.numeric(ffqlong$par_edu)` before computing the aggregate. Of course it works only if `par_edu` is really a column of numbers.

or:

2. Apply the `round` only on numeric columns of the aggregate.